# Eclipse Indigo "Install new Software" has "Next" button disabled in Ubuntu 10.04.4

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-10.04

I just downloaded the Eclipse Java EE IDE (64-bit) for Ubuntu 10.04.4. I was trying to install some plug-ins by using Help -->  Install New Software. But when I select any site in the consequently appearing dialog-box, the "Next" button is not enabled.

I tried un-installing and re-installing eclipse, getting the tar file of eclipse, even the classic IDE of eclipse, running eclipse as root and nothing seems to work.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

P.S. I am attaching a screenshot of the problem [image: "Install New Software Fail!!"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the install dialog got squeshed vertically. There should be a big table of stuff to install. Try making the dialog bigger.

Comment: I would say that has to be one of the #facepalm moments. I also ran eclipse with the -clean option and it seemed to show the big table. So anyways, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Click on **already installed** link and see if the plugin is already installed. Uninstall it -> Restart -> Repeat -> Next button should be enabled